# Dropbox API - search in files and content

Tags: search, dropbox

I'm trying to build Java app that search for files including a "word" in a content of files inside dropbox folder.

As we can see in Dropbox docs:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http#documentation-files-search

we can do that using "filename_and_content".

I suppose that the fragment of Java code allowing to set "filename_and_content" should look like this:

```
SearchBuilder searchBuilder = client.files.searchBuilder("/duke/duke/Daily_Activity_Reports", "plik");

searchBuilder.mode(Files.SearchMode.filenameAndContent);
```

But how should I use this SearchBuilder in searching?

Comment: [Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/204370856-dropbox-api-search-for-files-and-content ]

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the [`SearchBuilder`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v2.0.x/com/dropbox/core/v2/Files.SearchBuilder.html) object configured the way you want, you can then call the `start` method on it to begin searching. The documentation for the `start` method can be found [here](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v2.0.x/com/dropbox/core/v2/Files.SearchBuilder.html#start()).

It returns a [`SearchResults`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v2.0.x/com/dropbox/core/v2/Files.SearchResults.html) object with the results, as well as `more`, which tells you if there are more results available, and `start`, which you should pass back to the [`start`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v2.0.x/com/dropbox/core/v2/Files.SearchBuilder.html#start()) method in order to get the rest of the results.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Greg.

Comment: I use searchBuilder.mode(Files.SearchMode.filenameAndContent) to enable searching through content of files, but it's not working have you got any idea why?

Comment: What do you mean by "not working" exactly? One thing that may be relevant is that content search currently only works for business accounts.

Comment: Ohhhhhh. So that may be the reason!!

Comment: You were right. It is working after switching to business account. Thanks a lot

Comment: Has this changed recently to only work with business accounts?

Comment: @powder366 This is a known issue unrelated to the account type. We're looking into it.

Comment: Ok. Let me know on your progress or if I can help. Im having this problem with my user for my Android app. Ticket at Dropbox  #5169488:

Comment: @powder366 This should be fixed now.